# Creating partials with a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm compiling a feed for my company's different blogs.  The format is going to be identical for each feed with only different posts being loaded in, so I'd love to go DRY and use a partial.

We originally were writing out the http request about 10 times (that's how many blogs we have) and then I got this brilliant (or maybe not so much...) idea to try and build a directive that would run the http request with a link attribute that would pull back the data that would be specific to that feed.

So, I want to have a dynamic directive that makes dynamic http requests and receives dynamic data sets that I can then feed to one partial.  I would have expected/hoped the `{{test}}` to change based on the value of the `link` attribute.

I'm definitely new to angular.  Am I going about this the wrong way?  Thanks in advance!

```
app.directive('tabs', function(){
  return {
     restrict: "A",
     scope: false,
     link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.test = attrs.link;
        scope.$apply;
        //dynamic $http function here               
  }
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9D9LTCnBOGAo2ftA1jbU?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your goal is.  Is it to limit the number of requests being made?  Or is it to create something reusable so you can create a directive that can be plunked down and handle any blog?  These aren't mutually exclusive, but solving one doesn't necessarily solve the other.

Here's roughly what I'd do.

```
app.directive('blog', ['BlogService', function(BlogService) {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       templateUrl: '/app/views/blog.html',
       scope: {
           url: '='
       },
       controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.loadFeed = function() {
              $scope.loading = true;
              BlogService.loadFeed( $scope.url ).success( function(result) {
                  $scope.feed = result.feed;
              } ).complete( function() {
                  $scope.loading = false;
              });
          }
       },
       link: function(scope, element, attribs) {
          scope.$watch('url', function(newVal,oldVal) {
             if( newVal ) {
                scope.loadFeed( scope.url );
             }
          });
       }
}]);
```

The template:

```
<div class="feed">
    <span ng-show="loading">Loading feed. Please wait...</span>
    <ul ng-hide="loading">
        <li ng-repeat="post in feed">
           <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
           <h2>{{post.date}}</h2>
           <p>{{post.description}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The service:

```
app.factory( 'BlogService', [ '$http', function($http) {
   return {
      loadFeed: function(url) {
         return $http.get( url );
      },
      loadAllBlogs: function() {
         // this might be a service on your service that 
         // returns all of the blogs for each tab maybe.
         return $http.get('/service/blog/all'); 
      }
   }
}]);
```

Now you can roll this up into a larger controller that understands your individual feeds and it can set the url on your feeds like:

```
<div>
   <ul class="tabs">
      <li ng-repeat="blog in blogs" ng-click="selectBlog(blog)>blog.name</li>
   </ul>

   <!-- here is where I use the directive above -->
   <div blog url="selectedBlog.url"></div>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xjarG8Z2HcCfjtIZbB1w?)

Comment: I didn't realize you could declare a controller within a directive!  Does make those `$scope` variable specific to elements with that directive?

Comment: When you define a scope property in your directive declaration to accept parameters (ie url in my example) then that scope is separate from other scopes, and manipulating and storing information into the directives scope doesn't affect other scopes.  But you can't see things in the other scopes either.  But that's OK because we may reuse this directive several times on a page and not conflict with each usage.  It encapsulates the state of an instance of a directive so that it's owned by that directive and no one else.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still trying to digest this.  I'm still trying to work through how you're pulling url from the element and getting it into your controller.

Comment: It seems like the `result.feed` doesn't stay unique to each one.

Comment: result.feed is just the results from the service call.  It will be unique per call because the URL should be different between requests.  That url should be different for each blog which will be in the Controller (not shown).  This is very similar to how Object Oriented designs work.  Maybe a plunkr is in order...please hold.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.directive('tabs', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            $http.get(attrs.link).success(angular.noop);
    }
}]);
```

Require `$http` service from directive, and use it in `link`